# text-shadow with em instead of px?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple

```
text-shadow: 0.05em 0.05em 0.05em black;
```

I open in Google Chrome and there is no shadow at all!
I change it to

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
```

and it works!
What is the matter?

Comment: So stupid of me not to tell you my font size when I spoke of the em unit. Thank you all!

Comment: I just always forget that I have to specify a magnitude with the unit, so I type `em` and my css is ignored so I get no shadow. When I wrote `1em`, it worked. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0.05em` is too small value and your shadow falls behind the text. Try to increase it a little - http://jsfiddle.net/zd4qF/

**UPDATE**

Your code with `.05em` will actually work in FF, but not Chrome. That's because of rounding logic in the browsers - FF rounds anything smaller than `1px` to `1px`, Chrome floors it to `0`

Comment: explains why my shadows in firefox tend to be bigger.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the link bellow you can see the conversion rates between **em** and **pixels**
Since you asked for 0.05em that is way smaller than 1px :)

http://pxtoem.com/

For eg.

**1px** should be around **0.063em** which makes **0.05 em** less than **1px** thus less than anything you can display.

Answer (score 1):

It's not visible because the value is too low. `em` is proportional to the font-size. The smaller the font, the smaller everything that's declared depending on the font using `em`.

Here's an example with different font-sizes. In this example 0.5em can be seen when the font size is 48pt, but not when it'2 12 pt. See http://jsfiddle.net/JwNbj/1/

Answer (score 0):

EM is a relative attribute and depends on your font size defined in the body element or when you defined it also relative, then it depends on the options defined in the user's browser options.
when your font size is 20px, then 1px will be 0,05em. greets.